# Issue using XMLSerializer to Serialize and Deserialize

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, windows-ce, xmlserializer

I am working on C# sockets and using `XMLSerializer` to send and receive data. 
The XML data are sent from a server to a client over a network connection using TCP/IP protocol. The `XML.Serializer.Serialize(stream)` serializes the XML data and send them over the socket connection but when I want to use  the `XMLSerializer.Deserialize(stream)` to read. The sent data returns a xml parse error.

Here is how I'm serializing:

```
Memory Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
FrameClass frame= new FrameClass ();
frame.string1 = "hello";
frame.string2 = "world";

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(frame.GetType());
xmlSerializer.Serialize(ms, frame);

socket.Send(ms.GetBuffer(), (int)ms.Length, SocketFlags.None);
```

Deserializing:

```
FrameClass frame;
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FrameClass));
frame= (FrameClass)xml.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(sockCom.SocketBuffer));
listbox1.Items.Add(frame.string1);
listbox2.Items.Add(frame.string2);
```

I think it has something to do with sending the data one right after another.
Can anyone teach me how to do this properly?

Comment: I would use the code sample formatter in the text edit box.  Highlight your code and click on the "{}" option in the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you received all of the data before attempting to deserialize (it's not clear from your code).  I'd be inclined to receive all of the data into a local string and the deserialize from that rather than attempting to directly deserialize from the socket.  It would also allow you to actually look at the data in the debugger before deserializing it.

Comment: What's happening is when I received the message, in the socket buffer, it's stacking all the received object so now when I'm attempting to convert that socket buffer into an object (in this case frame class) it's throwing an error for the reason that the buffer has multiple frame class object in it.

Comment: Yes, so pull all of the frames out, put them into a single string and deserialize from that.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, you're saying that instead of casting it into Frame Class object, cast it to string? then process the XML, which is in string format to the frame class object?

Comment: Also, it's throwing me an error <FrameClass xmlns=''> was not expected. when I try to deserialize. I'm sorry it's just I have never worked with XML and XMLSerializer before. I'm used on binary formatters which I cant use for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    FrameClass frame= new FrameClass ();
    frame.string1 = "hello";
    frame.string2 = "world";

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(frame.GetType());
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(ms, frame);
    ms.Flush();
    socket.Send(ms.GetBuffer(), (int)ms.Length, SocketFlags.None);
}
```

---

If you're sending the Frame XML one right after the other, then you're not sending an XML document. The XML Serializer will attempt to deserialize your entire document!

I don't have time to research this now, but look into the XmlReaderSettings property for reading XML fragments. You would then create an XmlReader over the memorystream with those settings, and call it in a loop.

The important thing is to flush the stream. It's also useful to put the stream in a `using` block to ensure it's cleaned up quickly.

Comment: It didnt work, It gave me an XMLException.. Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 9, position 18. Remember that I am sending the frame class one right after another. A good example is having your code above in a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what @John said about the Flush call, your code looks alright.

You say you're sending multiple FrameClass data pieces, then the code should work sending just a single piece of data.

If you need to send multiple data objects, then you cannot send them all in one go, otherwise the deserialization process will stumble over the data.
You could setup some communication between the server & the client so the server knows what it's getting.

client: I have some data

Server: ok I'm ready, send it

client: sends

Server: done processing

repeat process...